# How to get files under Code tab in a job using AzureML python SDK

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-component

I'm trying to access the files/artifacts located in the code tab under an AzureML job. When using the [azureml.core.run.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py) class, the only methods suitable could be `get_file_names()` and `download_files` but they only list files under the Outputs + logs tab.

Is there a workaround to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Designer we can export the code. For Automl we could see the image as show below. you can use the run.download_files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code tab should contain your working directory, with the main.py and so on.
In your scripts you should be able to access the files normally with the path "./path/to/file/file.txt".
If you have created an .amlignore, the files it contains will not be uploaded with the run command.